# Install shiny app using RInno; select R install location

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an install package for a Shiny app. I selected the `include_R = TRUE` option which bundle R with the installer. Everything is working OK except that R is installed automatically in a location different than the one that I need. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can change that behavior using the `R_flags` argument of `run` or `create_app`. For example, if you want to install R in each user's documents folder:

```
create_app(
  app_name = "myapp",
  app_dir = "app",
  R_flags = '/SILENT /DIR=""{userdocs}""')
```

In this example, I've combined [Inno Setup constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) with [R_flags](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-customize-the-installation_003f). You can replace the Inno Setup constant, `{userdocs}`, with a full path or combine the two, i.e. `""{userdocs}\\R""`

For more information, see `?run` (soon to be renamed `run_section` in RInno 0.2.0 because of namespace conflicts).